# Linq and Dictionary and converting array values

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code

```
IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<Control>>
```

I need to convert it to

```
IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
```

using ClientID as the new value.

Does anybody know how to do this in Linq instead iterating through the dictionary?

Thanks

Podge

Comment: To get the ClientID of all the values in the dictionary, *something's* going to have to iterate over it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without having a compiler by hand, something like this should work...

```
dictOne
  .ToDictionary(k=>k.Key, v=>v.Value.Select(c=>c.ClientID))
```

Comment: Thanks very much.
 I couldn't see the wood for the trees. I was thinking I would have to use SelectMany.

Answer (score 6):

Something like

```
IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<Control>> input = ...
IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> output = 
    input.ToDictionary(item => item.Key,
                       item => item.Value.Select(control => control.ClientID));
```